# How can I remove/filter/ignore some package from Emma (code coverage)

Tags: java, ant, filter, code-coverage, emma

I`m trying to **remove some package from my report** and having trouble.

Could some one give me some help?

I'm using EMMA in my *ant* process.

---

`<!-- Generate the emma report both in xml and html -->

<emma>

  <report

    sourcepath="${build.report.src}"

    metrics="class:${coverage.classes.min},method:${coverage.methods.min}">
    <fileset dir="${build.report.junit.data.dir}">

      <include name="*.emma"/>

    </fileset>

    <html outfile="${build.report.reports}/emma/raw.html" depth="method"/>

    <xml outfile="${build.report.tmp}/emma.xml" depth="method"/>

  </report>

</emma>`

---

I`ve tried to use:


`<filter excludes="com.my.package.*"/>`

But with **no** success :(

Answer (score 10):

Emma allows the use of filters at **instrumentation** phase to specify a set of files that need to be instrumented. In contrast you are trying to do this at **report generation** phase. The  [link given above](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch02s06s02.html#n11405) describes how to define the instrumentation set.

I've used filters like this:

```
<property name="emma.filter" value="-*.unittest.* -*.unittests.* -*.TST* -*TestCase -*Test -*TestSuite" />

<emma>
    <instr instrpath="${build.dir}"
        mode="overwrite"
        metadatafile="${build.dir}/coverage.em"
        filter="${emma.filter}" />
</emma>
```

You can also use nested <filter> elements under <instr>

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've tried *all* of the variations in the [documentation](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch02s06s02.html#n11405)...?

If so, I expect that you may have a typo, or something like that.  Can you provide the code you're using *with* the exclude syntax that doesn't work, and the header of the source file for the class that is incorrectly being included?