# Can I exclude auto generated code from Eclemma code coverage tool Java?

Tags: java, code-coverage, emma, jacoco

Is it possible to hide some of my code (for example autogenerated code) from eclemma code coverage tool. In c# there is an option to do it the option described [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2008/11/10/hiding-generated-code-from-code-analysis-metrics-and-test-coverage.aspx) , do we have something like this in Java?

EDITED:
I am not using ant, I use Eclema plugin for eclipce, is there any configuration that I can do to exclude some of my code from coverage tool.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove/filter/ignore some package from Emma (code coverage)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016117/how-can-i-remove-filter-ignore-some-package-from-emma-code-coverage)

Comment: I am interested in solution using eclemma plugin, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment this cannot be done as far as I know.

The planned EclEmma [Filtering Options](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/eclemma/wiki/FilteringOptions) may in the long run make this possible though.